# multiple lines d3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to do a simple plot with d3. It works fine when I plot only one line at time but I would like to make my code more generic.

My data are in this format (note that the 2 set of data may not contain the same amount of point and the time is not perfectly synchronize between my 2 sets of measure):

> var data = [{key: "kmm03", value:[{"time":1364108443000,"mesure":"1.6299999952316284"},{"time":1364108503000,"mesure":"1.100000023841858"},{"time":1364108563000,"mesure":"1.159999966621399"}},
>   {key: "kmm04", value:[{"time":1364108416000,"mesure":"2.690000057220459"},{"time":1364108476000,"mesure":"3.319999933242798"},{"time":1364108536000,"mesure":"3.140000104904175"},{"time":1364108596000,"mesure":"2.9800000190734863"}}]

Now I try to plot it like this but I cannot get the svg lines to dispay:

```
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 20, left: 40};
    var width = 780 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    var time_scale = d3.time.scale()
        //.domain(time_extent)
        .domain([1364108443000, 1364112559000])
        .range([0, width]);

    var mesure_scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,10])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var vis = d3.select("#box1")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



    var time_axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(time_scale)
        .orient("bottom");
    var mesure_axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(mesure_scale)
        .orient("left");

    var set_axis_t = vis.append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height +")")
      .call(time_axis);

    var set_axis_m = vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
    .call(mesure_axis);


    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d){return time_scale(d.time);})
        .y(function(d){return mesure_scale(d.mesure);});

    var group = vis.selectAll('path')
       .data(data)
       .enter().append('path')
       .attr("d", line);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

d3 [selection.data()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data) takes an array of elements. In your code the data var is an array of two objects. When you call line on d, d3 looks for time and measure properties in each element. These don't exist so no paths are appended.

The amount and time values you want to render are nested one layer down in the value property of each object.

To draw these, change the `.attr('d', line)` to `.attr("d", function(d) {return line(d.value);});`

[Here is a working version.](http://bl.ocks.org/andrewStaroscik/5232640) To make it work I made a few other changes:

1- closing brackets of the value arrays were missing

2- `.selectAll('path')` was not working for the data because it was conflicting with the path elements in the axes. To address this, I assigned the data paths the class visline and use `.selectAll('.visline')` to access them

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me a lot of time to understand my mistake. One last question, what is the most elegant way to find the max value in each nested set of value to define the domain of my axe?

Comment: take a look at the y.domain() lines in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955. He is working with a similar data structure.